# NetSuite Locations

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Hi I need to access the addresses in the locations object of the multi-locations NetSuite install using SuiteScript, it doesn't seem to work the same as when you access addresses of customers. I googled and couldn't find any good info, thanks for anyhelp, I am using Mont-Blanc version

Comment: Where are you trying to access the location? In the item-level or transaction level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address on the location record is a body field if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

use the schema browser to determine the field name
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/schema/record/account.html